# Убрал код всплывающего окна, но он все еще появляется на странице

Tags: javascript

[image: Вот что выскакивает. В исходниках и следов от этого нет!]

Написал код на javascript'е который появляется всплывающее окно, с "ОК" и "Cancel". Но потом удалил его. Но теперь каждый раз при загрузке страницы, трижды подряд выскакивает то самое окно. Тщательно все проверил, ни следа от кода, но все же появляется!

Прошу помочь! Могу весь код выложить. С ума сойду а то!

[Вот исходники. Тут не много. Выложил в JSFiddle PHP страницы](http://jsfiddle.net/248FJ/)

Comment: Очистите кэш. ctrl+f5, если не поможет, то ctrl+shift+del.

Comment: не думаю что из за кэша. Т.к и из других устройств та же проблема

Comment: Не выкладывайте на всеобщее обозрение доступы к вашей базе данных. Изменил ваш вопрос, затерев эти данные.

Comment: кто поможет?

Answer (score 1):

На будущее, неплохо бы посмотреть исходники. Так сложно сказать, что там у вас происходит. Если скрипта, вызывающего окно нет, то почистите кеш.

Comment: не думаю что из за кэша. Т.к и из других устройств та же проблема. Выложил исходники. Смотрите в вопрос